# In JavaScript, how do default function values play with monomorphism

Tags: javascript

Curious about the scenario where the developer is trying to keep a function monomorphic, but uses default function parameters in JavaScript. So something like

Example A:

```
 const myFunc = (o = {x: 0}) => {
   return o.x;
}
```

And also the situation where the argument being passed is not defaulted to the same shape, something like

Example B :

```
const myFunc = (o = {}) => {
       return o.x;
    }
```

Do either of these example remain monomorphic if the default function parameters are used instead of the correct passed shape? I am curious about the optimization of these scenarios.

Comment: your first example should be: `const myFunc = (o = { x = 0 }) => ...`, the colon is used to rename they key in the object

Comment: @duxfox No, what you wrote is a syntax error. The OP has it right (it's an object literal)

Comment: oh, my mistake =|

Comment: ah I see, I generally do this, so it threw me off: `func = ({ key1 = 'x', key2 = 'y' } = {}) => {..`